# SQL Server collation and its equivalent in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, collation

Legacy system, backed by SQL Server, has unique indexes using collation `Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`. It compares things using charset Latin 1, encoded using CP-1252 (`CP1` part), case insensitive, accent insensitive.

Which collation should I use in Postgres to get exactly the same behavior?

Comment: Maybe you could explain what behaviour that is, since Postgres experts who could answer the question might not know what the specified collation does in SQL Server...

Comment: @mustaccio Done.

Comment: You'll need to check `pg_collation` to see the available collations. If none matches your needs, you can create your own [ICO collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcollation.html). There are several posts here and on stackoverflow.com on how to create a case-insensitive ICU collation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to create a collation that behaves absolutely the same. The best would probably be this ICU collation:

```
CREATE COLLATION general_ci_ai (
   PROVIDER = icu,
   DETERMINISTIC = FALSE,
   LOCALE = '@ColStrength=primary'
);
```

However, you cannot have an non-deterministic collation as database collation. You will have to use it explicitly in column definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
   col text COLLATE general_ci_ai
);
```